# Calculating Day of Week is JS with Sakamoto, Wang, Schwerdtfeger

Tags: javascript, dayofweek

I am trying to implement a "get day of week" (Su=0,Mo,...,Sa=6) function in plain javascript and stumbled upon the Tomohiko Sakamoto Algorithm, Wang and Schwerdtfeger. As far as i understand all three apply the same concept, just with different steps, so i ll just focus on the Sakamoto alorithm here for simplicity's sake.
I wrote a simple test function to verify the correctness of their results - yet all of them seem to go wrong on the 2004-March-1st which is calculated to be Sunday(0) while actually being a Monday(1).

Am i mistaken or are there any special boundaries to the algorithm that i am not aware of?

```js
const DaysInMonth = [
  31, // Jan
  28, // Feb has 29 in leap years!
  31, // Mar
  30, // Apr
  31, // May
  30, // Jun
  31, // Jul
  31, // Aug
  30, // Sep
  31, // Okt
  30, // Nov
  31 // Dec
]

function getWeekDaySakamoto (y, m ,d) {
  const LookupTable = [0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4]
  let year = y
  if (m < 3) {
   year -= 1
  }
  return Math.floor((year + year / 4 - year / 100 + year / 400 + LookupTable[m - 1] + d) % 7)
}

let isLeap = false
let wd = 0
let prevWd = -1
// we need to findout where the algo goes wrong
for (let y = 2000; y < 2030; y++) {
  isLeap = y % 4 === 0
  if (isLeap && y % 100 === 0 && y % 400 !== 0) {
    isLeap = false
  }
  for (let m = 1; m <= 12; m++) {
    for (let d = 1; isLeap && m === 2 ? (d <= 29) : (d <= DaysInMonth[m - 1]); d++) {
      wd = getWeekDaySakamoto(y, m ,d)
      if (prevWd === -1) {
        // initialize the value first
        prevWd = wd
      } else {
        if ((wd === 0 && prevWd === 6) ||
          (wd === 1 && prevWd === 0) ||
          (wd === 2 && prevWd === 1) ||
          (wd === 3 && prevWd === 2) ||
          (wd === 4 && prevWd === 3) ||
          (wd === 5 && prevWd === 4) ||
          (wd === 6 && prevWd === 5)) {
          console.log(`checked ${y}-${m}-${d} = ${wd}`)
          prevWd = wd
        } else {
          throw new Error(`expected ${y}-${m}-${d} to be a follow up on ${prevWd} but got ${wd}`)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Final error message of the validation script is `Error: expected 2004-3-1 to be a follow up on 0 but got 0` As 2004-2-29 was a `0` (which is correct), 2004-3-1 should be a `1` but is calculated to be a `0` instead.